# How to remove an app from a monorepo into it's own repository

Tags: javascript, typescript, monorepo, turborepo

I'm just starting to look into monorepo for my personal and freelancing projects.

Specifically, I'm looking into Turborepo as a build system to help manage and work within the monorepo.

Reasons (not exhaustive) are to leverage shared packages, similiar configuration setups etc. to build projects better and more efficiently.  Rather than build out feature X from a different project from scratch, I can reuse the feature X that was built previously and access/manage it easily with a monorepo.

However, one potentially blocking issue is the following example:

- Company A needs application built (let's say Node.js).
- I build it out in a monorepo leveraging several shared packages from other previous projects that fit the project needs.
- Company A (at some later date) then wants to bring project in-house and have full control of code.  (I can no longer keep the app in my monorepo and am required to hand off source code).
- Export the application including any shared packages leveraged within the monorepo into its own repository to hand off to Company A for the transition.

Is there any tooling that makes this possible without manually needing to rip out the needed pieces myself?

Am I thinking about monorepos in the right way in the first place?